# Sqlalchemy class is not iterable / converting relationship to a set

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, set, one-to-many

I'm trying to convert a one-to-many part of a many-to-many relationship to a python set(). See the following play example for code:

```
message_tos = Table('message_tos', Base.metadata,                                
    Column('message_id', Integer, ForeignKey('message.id')), 
    Column('address_id', Integer, ForeignKey('address.id'))
)

class Address(Base):
    address = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    emails = relationship('Message')

    def __init__(self, address):
        self.address = address

class Email(Base):
    from = relationship('Address', backref='from')
    to = relationship('Address', secondary=message_tos, backref='messages_to')
    message_id = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)

...

def whatever(*args, **kwargs):
    """
        ...
    """
    email = session.query(Email).filter(Email.message_id==message_id).first()
    blah = set(email.to).union(email.from) # This lines throws an error that Address is not iterable
```

Is there any way to run the `set(email.to)` code  (which places an Address object into a set), or am I going about this completely the wrong way? Obviously, I could just do set([email.to]), however this is an entire extra order of complexity (and this function may be called multiple times with potentially *very* long .to or .from lists) which I'd rather not have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error most probably occurs not in the `set(email.to)` part, but in `.union(email.from)`, since the `email.from` is not iterable. According to your code, `email.from` is an instance of `Address`.

This should work though: `blah = set(email.to).union([email.from])`. *I assume that did not really call the property `from`, as it is a reserved keyword in python. I guess `sender` is a good name.*

---

*Also note that in SA searching for a primary key can be done clearer with the [`Query.get`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get):*

```
email = session.query(Email).get(message_id)
```

Comment: Yeah, it's not called `.from` in the actual code; I assumed clarity was better than exact code.
Thanks for the searching-for-pkey tip, too (though in this case message_id isn't actually a primary key (I should probably redesign this part))!